# Different notations for outer and Kronecker product

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I see that [Kronecker and outer products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#:%7E:text=The%20outer%20product%20contrasts%20with,and%20produces%20a%20block%20matrix) have the same symbolic notation. Their output is though different. Is there some modern notation to distinguish both operations?

Comment: Just don't think in terms of the outer product at all. The Kronecker product is the better operation and the outer product, in terms of the Kronecker product, is $u^T \otimes v$.

Comment: Great! I thank you, sir.

Comment: I hope this article may suffice as thank gift: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19680380302